# Path2D - drawing multiply versions of the shape

Tags: java, draw

I'm trying to zoom the previously created shape. It works, but there are previous states of the shape, which are visible on the screen. I can't make it works that it shows only the last state of my shape. I do have a call `repaint()` in the end of the method which changes the size. Please tell me what code should I paste here, I give you the most appropriate one for me. I don't know if it's obvious or not, but I'm making this in `JFrame`.

**Codes** and **image** are below.

(a.other is the shape, valuesX and valuesY are arrays which contains where shape's points are located)

my class to draw it:

```
public class ZOtherShape extends Path2D.Float


a.other.moveTo(a.other.valuesX[0],a.other.valuesY[0]);

for (int index = 1; index < a.other.valuesX.length; index++)
    a.other.lineTo(a.other.valuesX[index], a.other.valuesY[index]);

a.other.closePath();
g2d.fill(a.other);


g2d.setPaint(Color.BLACK);


a.other.moveTo(a.other.valuesX[0],a.other.valuesY[0]);

for (int index = 1; index < a.other.valuesX.length; index++)
    a.other.lineTo(a.other.valuesX[index], a.other.valuesY[index]);

a.other.closePath();
g2d.draw(a.other);
```

**[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pn3Gc.jpg)**

Comment: You are adding lines to the same shape. `lineTo` **adds** a line to the given shape.

Comment: I understand it, but I can't find an idea to make it worked correctly. I created the shape, and then I wanted to use only fill and draw method, so I removed everything except for fill and draw (in case when zoom mode is active, in create mode everything is left), but in this case the shape doesn't zoom at all. Can I remove the lines that exist already?

Comment: If you remove the existing lines, you won't have the original lines to copy. You need to copy it to another shape, and then create a new shape with the lines in zoom mode.

Comment: I just found what I wanted, I had to add: "a.other.reset();" before painting, now it works correctly. But thank you for your help, I didn't realise that I was making just more and more lines in my shape :)